# why it is giving run time exception as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

When I run below code then I am getting thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
 class InterviewBit{
           int fun (int n) 
           {
               int result;
               result = fun (n - 1); //it gives error on this line
               return result;
           }
       } 
    class Driver{
           public static void main(String args[]) 
           {
               InterviewBit ib = new InterviewBit() ;
               System.out.print(ib.fun(12));
           }
       }
```

Can anyone please explain why it is giving this error?

Comment: Think about it, what is the condition for the recursion to end? Will the recursive call ever get to `return result`? When using recursion, you need _some condition_ at which point the recursion actually returns. This is not the case in your snippet, therefore you get the `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: The condition of n to be reached to some value and then to terminate the execution? https://stackoverflow.com/users/11441011/maloomeister

Comment: I did something like
if (n <= 1) 
            return 1;
result = fun (n - 1);
       return result;
and I debugged the code, I do see the value of n getting reduced and when it reached to 1 it checks the condition if n <= 1

Answer (score 0):

Your program is exceeding the allocated call stack memory by having a `fun()` method that calls itself over and over again. You need to tell that method when to stop calling itself again, for example, when n reaches `1` or `0` or any other number.

```
class InterviewBit{
  int fun (int n) {
    int result;
    if (n<=1) return 1;
    result = fun (n - 1);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did something like if (n <= 1) return 1; result = fun (n - 1); return result; and I debugged the code, I do see the value of n getting reduced and when it reached to 1 it checks the condition if n <= 1  
@mario varchmin

Comment: @kavitaKulkarni With that change, does it still produce the StackOverflow error?

Comment: No, it doesn't! Thank you, I assume, what causes StackOverflowError is, when recursion doesn't check when value goes/reduces to 1 or 0 then it will throw this error.